# add UIButton in the space not used by a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm in a UITableView implementation file, and used :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
}
```

So my table view do not occupy the entire screen so I could display buttons in the space left, but

```
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

does not seems to work to make the button appear in that space left. I think thats because its adding the button inside the table view since 'self' is the table view. But I don't know the solution to use the empty space, any help?

Comment: what is the frame of your button?

Comment: you are using `UITableViewController`?

Comment: can u add the screen shot which type u need

Comment: I'm using UITableViewController because when I tried to initialize a new UITableView in an UIViewController the same methods used in UITableViewController to populate the table and use the cell at tap didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add buttons like that into an UITableView (mainly because it's a subclass of UIScrollView).

I suggest you use a `UIViewController` instead, and add your `UITableView` plus any additional views you need to the main controller view.

Comment: Yes I tried this, but to populate and use the cells and all the methods that I am used to work in a UITableViewController does not seems to work in a UITableView inside a UIViewController. For example, how this method should be modified to work in the ViewController.m file populating properly my TableView :

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   
? Thank you

Comment: Set the `UITableView`'s delegate and dataSource to your new `viewController`.

Comment: How can I do it without storyboard?

Comment: tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;